# Sandbox command line from network?

Tags: command-line

Similar to how I can run `time command`, I'd like to run a command such as `dont_allow_network_access command`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [lxc](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/).
This package contains a tool named **lxc-unshare** which you can use as follows:

```
# lxc-unshare -s NETWORK -- su username -c 'ping 127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: `unshare` from util-linux does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a list of your network devices:

```
ifconfig -a
```

If your device you want to diable is eth0

```
ifconfig eth0 down
```

and to turn it back on:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```